# Set iOS Address Book Image in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, addressbookui

I am trying to integrate the AddressBookUI API into my iOS 5 app to display selected content in a table view. I have been able to implement the AddressBook Picker and set it so when a user selects a person from their address book, it populates the label of the cell in the TableView. I would also like it to be able to display the image of the selected person in the same cell if one exists and a default missing picture image if there is not one.

I can't see to get my head around how to store both the name and the image data in the same TableView cell.

Anyone have any suggestions of how I might accomplish this. I have read the developer docs and know i should be using the ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat command. I just can't seem to get it to implement into the tableview cell.

Here are the snippets of code I have so far:

```
// Store the name into memory when the user selects, then dismiss the view.
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
{

    NSString *selectedPerson = (__bridge NSString *)ABRecordCopyCompositeName(person);


    [people insertObject:selectedPerson atIndex:0];

    if (ABPersonHasImageData(person) == TRUE) {
        NSLog(@"Person has an image!");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Person does not have an image.");
    }

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    [self.tableView reloadData];

    return NO;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    PartyCell *cell = (PartyCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    cell.backgroundView = [[GradientView alloc] init];

    cell.personLabel.text = [people objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.personImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"missing.png"]; // THIS NEEDS TO DISPLAY THE SELECTED USERS PICTURE. CURRENTLY SHOWS A DEFAULT USER.

    return cell;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a simple solution: store the image of the selected contact in a new NSMutableArray at index 0 each time.

```
UIImage *image =[UIImage imageWithData:(__bridge NSData *)ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(person, kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail)];

        [peopleImage insertObject:image atIndex:0];
```

The images can then be loaded like normal into a cell by calling the array in the UITabelView

```
cell.personImage.image = [peopleImage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you get a UIImage from the ABRecordRef:

```
[UIImage imageWithData:(NSData *)ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(person, kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail)];
```

Then, you can set the UITableViewCell's imageView's image like:

```
[[cell imageView] setImage: image];
```

Couple other links that may help you:

http://www.chrisdanielson.com/tag/uitableviewcell/

http://goddess-gate.com/dc2/index.php/post/421

Comment: I have tried these two lines of code, but its not working for me. I edited my original post with the two sections of code I am working with.